# Sending dynamic data to webserver

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, web-server

I am trying to send data to a php file via http GET method.

I am able to send static data but I am unable to send dynamic data.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial gprsSerial(9, 10);

char inchar;
int ledPin = 13;
int sensorPin = A0;
int sensorValue = 0;

boolean gs = true;
boolean es = true;
boolean ss = false;

void setup()
{
  gprsSerial.begin(9600);
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CNMI = 2,2,0,0");
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
   currentMillis = millis();
   if(gprsSerial.available()>0)
  {
    inchar = gprsSerial.read();
    if (inchar == '#')
    {
      delay(10);
      inchar = gprsSerial.read();
      if (inchar == '1')
      {
        Serial.println("System Enabled");
        ss = true;
        snd_msg(0);
      }
      else if (inchar == '0')
      {
        Serial.println("System Disabled");
        ss = false;
        snd_msg(1);        
      }
      delay(10);
      inchar = gprsSerial.read();
      if (inchar == '1')
      {
        Serial.println("Geofence Enabled");
        gs = true;
        snd_msg(2);        
      }
      else if (inchar == '0')
      {
        Serial.println("Geofence Disabled");
        gs = false;
        snd_msg(3);        
      }
      delay(10);
    }
  }
    gprs();
    delay(10000);
}

void toSerial()
{
  while(gprsSerial.available()!=0)
  {
    Serial.write(gprsSerial.read());
  }
}
 void snd_msg(int a)
{
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
  delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+918148090646\"\r"); // Replace x with mobile number
  delay(1000);
  if ( a == 0)
  {
    gprsSerial.println("System Enabled");
  }
  else if ( a == 1)
  {
    gprsSerial.println("System Disabled");
  }
  else if ( a == 2)
  {
    gprsSerial.println("Geofence Enabled");
  }
  else if ( a == 3)
  {
    gprsSerial.println("Geofence Disabled");
  }     
  delay(100);
   gprsSerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
  delay(1000);
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CNMI = 2,2,0,0");
  delay(1000);
}
void vibra_sensor()
{
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
  if (sensorValue > 500)
  {
    es = true;
    break;
  }
  else
    es = false;
  delay(500);
  }  
  delay(1000);
}
void gprs()
{
  vibra_sensor();
  Serial.println("Config SIM900...");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Done!...");
  gprsSerial.flush();
  Serial.flush();

  // attach or detach from GPRS service 
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CGATT?");
  delay(100);
  toSerial();


  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();

  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"www\"");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();

  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();
  // initialize http service
  gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
   delay(6000); 
   toSerial();

   // set http param value 
 **gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"adnansait74.000webhostapp.com/operation.php?timestamp=02:50:00&latitude=11.374545&longitude=76.728986&gfence=OFF&estatus=OFF&sstatus=ON\"");**
   delay(5000);
   toSerial();

   // set http action type 0 = GET, 1 = POST, 2 = HEAD
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
   delay(6000);
   toSerial();

   // read server response
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPREAD"); 
   delay(1000);
   toSerial();

   gprsSerial.println("");
   gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPTERM");
   toSerial();
   delay(300);

   gprsSerial.println("");
   delay(10000);
   gprsSerial.println("AT+CNMI = 2,2,0,0");
  delay(1000);
}
```

**What I've Tried**

1.) Saving URL in a string

```
String URL = "adnansait74.000webhostapp.com/operation.php?timestamp=02:50:00&latitude=11.374545&longitude=76.728986&gfence=OFF&estatus=OFF&sstatus=";
    URL += ss;
    gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"+URL\"");
```

Doesn't Work

2.)Attaching values using print statement

```
gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"adnansait74.000webhostapp.com/operation.php?timestamp=02:50:00&latitude=11.374545&longitude=76.728986&gfence=OFF&estatus=OFF&sstatus=");
gprsSerial.println(ss+"\"");
```

3.)Entering value directly in URL

```
gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"adnansait74.000webhostapp.com/operation.php?timestamp=02:50:00&latitude=11.374545&longitude=76.728986&gfence=OFF&estatus=OFF&sstatus="+ss+"\");
```

**Error**

```
invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'
```

I'm using an arduino uno and a sim 900a GSM module.

**QUESTION**

How do I send dynamic values for **gfence, sstatus, estatus**?

I am also using a messaging service, the code is included. **The help I need is in the gprs() function.**

The data I need to send is,

gfence from gs

sstatus from ss

estatus from es

Comment: How does this not work? The GPS module returns an error? The HTTP server returns an error? Your PHP script returns an error?

Comment: it is unclear what you mean by static data and dynamic data.

Comment: `boolean ss = false;` ..... `URL += ss;` .... `..... binary 'operator+'` ............... you cannot concatenate a boolean value `True`  .... you can concatenate a string value `"abc123"` or `"True"`

Comment: `+URL` is not a valid URL. The syntax highlighting should have given you a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split it up:

```
gprsSerial.print(F("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"adnansait74.000webhostapp.com/operation.php?timestamp=02:50:00&latitude=11.374545&longitude=76.728986&gfence=OFF&estatus=OFF&sstatus="));
gprsSerial.print(ss);
gprsSerial.println(F("\""));
```

Note the use of `print` on each part up until the *last* part which is the only one that uses `println` in order to terminate the line.

Also note the use of the `F()` macro to reduce the wastage of RAM that string constants cause.

Comment: F() for one character?

Comment: Sure. Frugality is key with 2k ram

Comment: ok, I eventually googled that it is has no overhead in code

Comment: @Juraj I could have switched to `Serial.println('"');` (i.e., use a single `char`), but that would most likely have confused the OP. Best to keep things simple.